# .Net communication between API and Azure functions app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I am currently solving a possibly trivial problem. I have an API service where I receive some data, which I process and send to Azure Functions service which is actually an archive (database) using message broker (+blob storage). In the archive service I use Power BI to create reports. However, there is now a need to get the data from the archive service to the API so I can provide it using the API and get it to the frontend.

Of course, you could probably create Azure Functions HTTP and stick it in some gateway, but I don't know if that's exactly right. Unfortunately I can't find much of an article on this so I'm turning to you.
So my question is how do I get the data from the archive service (Azure functions) into the API service?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Supposing you had such a mechanism - how do you propose getting that information from the Api Service to the front end (or to whatever needs that information)?

Comment: @auburg Well either it would be through api gateway i.e. http function would be connected to api gateway. Or I would call the http function directly from the project's api, but I don't like either of these options.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTTP-triggered function and call this from your API.

Comment: Is that really right? Most articles I've read warn against this very thing. That's why I asked this question. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture

https://medium.com/@john_freeman/querying-data-across-microservices-8d7a4667668a

Comment: @PetrKlekner I think you are mistaken. I don't see anything in that article criticizing this approach. Your API is communicating to your front end. You need data from another backend service -- your API is a "facade" to your function app. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: But then that would mean that my API layer would call all services clearly just for querying data. But that would create a binding to the other services wouldn't it? I.e. one service crashes and my api doesn't work. And I provide that api to the frontend, but also to the customer they can use it as they wish. The article talks about this in the Direct queries between microservices section.